# Node.Js recieving hebrew as coded string from html form (method - post)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm using Node.Js to receive an HTML form and then using the data to query a database `(in SQL)`
if the data is in English. it's all good but when I'm typing data in Hebrew I get it as a coded string.
for example, a string in Hebrew : `"עברית"`
will be: `"%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA"`

**I'm already using this tag:**

> "meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /"

Comment: set column `Collation` `utf8_general_ci` in DB

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to decode it in the js file:

```
  function decode(str) {
            return decodeURIComponent(str.replace(/\+/g,  " "));
   }
```